# SVG g Element CSS Transitions Don’t Work Cross-Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, safari, css-transitions

I’m looking for an answer that specifically addresses browser support for `svg g element` css transitions.

To show the problem, [here](https://jsbin.com/lepepev/edit?html,output) is a representative example that works in Chrome, but only “jumps” between the two transform positions in Firefox and Safari.

Live Example: https://jsbin.com/lepepev/edit?html,output
`.rect-group` is being transitioned so that both `rect`s move together:

```
<style>
  .container {
    margin: 10em;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .test-rect {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .rect-group {
    transition: transform .25s ease-out 0s;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  .rect-group.normal {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
</style>
<svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="test-rect" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <title>test rect</title>
      <g class="rect-group">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" />
        <rect x="60" y="10" rx="10" ry="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" />
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="test-rect">
    <use xlink:href="#test-rect"></use>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- .normal is toggled on .rect-group via JS -->
```

So, just a simple transition on a transform for an `svg g element`. Again, it works in Chrome, but only “jumps” between the two transform positions in Firefox and Safari.

I used Chrome 58, Firefox 54 b14, Safari 10.1.1.

I'm hoping to find out:

1. Problem identification (what the actual problem is).
2. What (if any) work-around exists or alternate technique should be used (not just “use library X”). However, if “library X” solves the problem, the actual work-around/alt-technique will be found in the “library X” code, so it is still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that satisfies me. For my requirements, I’m looking to reference an svg in multiple places with `use`, address (via querySelector) and animate elements within each svg copy separately.

The svg `use` creates a closed shadow root. I’m not sure its easy (or desirable) to address and style deep elements in the closed shadow root. The way to address and style each svg copy from the parent document would require special selectors (::shadow or /deep/) that don’t have consistent browser support. In fact, Chrome is removing `/deep/` altogether (making it operate like a descendent combinator).
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4964279606312960

Because of the closed shadow root and cross-browser state of parent-to-shadow selectors, I’m electing to not try to animate `use` referenced svg elements via css.

However, cross-browser animating by css is still possible by rethinking how you structure your svg.

The other approaches I tried that work cross-browser are:

1. Inline svg (no-`use` reference). https://jsbin.com/xovidop/edit?html,output
2. Refactor the svg into distinct, reusable parts (that don’t need animation themselves) and `use` those from an inline svg that contains the parts can be easily addressed and styled.
   https://jsbin.com/qivebiy/edit?html,output

Hope this helps someone else.